# Why do most people in USA use Soyabean cooking oil even when it is refined?

Tags: oil, olive-oil

I checked on [this article](https://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/news/americas-most-widely-consumed-cooking-oil-causes-genetic-changes-brain) that most used oil is Soyabean oil, in USA.

**why the number of Soyabean oil still very high as compared to other oils like Olive oil?**

Comment: I'm right on the edge of voting to close this as about (or rather founded on) health claims.  Most cooking oils are highly refined anyway, so I'm not sure there's much to ask

Comment: I think your question is based on a number of false premises, but then I really don't see a question here anyway. Unrefined oil tends to be unsuitable for high temperature cooking which is why they refine it in the first place.

Comment: @GdD I watched a youtube video about oil heating and refined oil problems. And read similar things in an article a few days ago.

Comment: If you saw it on Youtube it must be true!

Comment: ‘Most used’ can mean a lot of different things, depending on how you measure.  For one, a lot of soy oil is sold as ‘vegetable oil’ in grocery stores, so a home cook who’s not paying attention may not realize they’re buying it.  But you only capture that if you’re looking at containers sold.   More likely, it’s by the liter, and so restaurants and factories will dominate.   And soy oil is cheap.  They’re not going to be doing mass frying in avocado oil unless it’s a brand/marketing thing.  They’ll use soy or peanut oil.

Comment: The University of California link does not support the claim that "most people in the USA use soybean oil."  It makes a different claim - that soybean oil is consumed more than any other oil.  Your question seems to be based on the (probably) false premise that American home cooks are choosing to cook with soybean oil.  The truth is, as stated in that linked article, "[soybean oil is] used for fast food frying, added to packaged foods, and fed to livestock."

Comment: Vikas:  your question as phrased does not permit factual answers; any answers to it would be strictly matters of opinion.  As such, it is not a good candidate for SA.  See: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question.  It is largely answered by [this paper](https://austinpublishinggroup.com/nutrition-food-sciences/fulltext/download.php?file=ajnfs-v1-id1004.pdf) and the answer is roughly that with interesterification you can make hardened soybean oil with no trans fats.  This is currently considered a healthy  option compared to saturated fats and hydrogenated fats.

Comment: @Juhasz so if Soyabean oil is not the one used most, how can I find most or commonly used cooking oils people in USA use at their home?

Answer (score 3):

We can't speak to health claims on this site, but common cooking oils in the US are canola, vegetable (a combination of canola, corn,soy, palm, and sunflower) and corn oils.  This probably comes down to the fact that they are plentiful and relatively inexpensive.

Comment: But I checked many graphs which suggest Soyabean is the most used oil.

Comment: Canola is second largest.

Comment: @Vikas used by who? Maybe it's used more for industrial purposes. I don't know of a single person who has ever used soyabean oil.